# I get "The code execution cannot proceed because avdevice-59.dll was not found." error when I run ffmpeg on my cmd

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, python, path

I'm trying to add FFmpeg to PATH. I have downloaded the windows executable ffmpeg files from the official website.

I have followed this [article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-windows)
to install ffmpeg into my computer and add to path. I have done everything & added ffmpeg to path through editing the system variables.

But then when I type ffmpeg in my cmd I get a weird confusing error saying "The code execution cannot proceed because avdevice-59.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem".

[image: System Error]

I have re-installed ffmpeg into my computer, but the problem just keeps on persisting. And yes, I have restarted my computer to see if that fixes it, but nothing, I'm still having the same problem.

I would like to get help on this please.

Comment: Is `avdevice-59.dll` existing somewhere in your disk?

Comment: That link guides you to download the static git build whereas your error can only occur with a shared build. Which file did you download?

Comment: Thanks @Gyan for the insight. I have now been able to solve it. I had the wrong ffmpeg.exe file in the same directory as the python directory.